# Laravel Action Route not Define

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have unique problem. I already create Route on web.php, on Controller, and Blade. and working on my localhost. but after publish to real server, I jus got error Action url\controller@function not define. this is my code.

```
Route::get('/timetableschedule', 'ManagementController@EmployeeTimeTable');
```

this is my web.php

```
public function EmployeeTimeTable(Request $request){
    $session = $request->session()->get('user.id');
    $companysession = $request->session()->get('user.location');
    $locationdata = DB::table('company')
    ->join('companyrole','companyrole.company_id','=','company.Company_id')
    ->join('users','users.id','=','companyrole.user_id')
    ->where('users.id',$session)
    ->get();

    $userlist = db::table('users')
    ->join('companyrole','users.id','companyrole.user_id')
    ->where('companyrole.company_id',$companysession)
    ->whereNotNull('users.NPK')
    ->select('users.id','users.name','users.NPK')
    ->orderby('users.name')
    ->get();

    $timesetting = db::table('time_leaving')
    ->where('company_id',$companysession)
    ->get();

    $leaveschedule = db::table('employee_leaving')
    ->join('users','employee_leaving.user_id','users.id')
    ->where('employee_leaving.company_id',$companysession)
    ->select('employee_leaving.leaving_date','users.name')
    ->get();

    return view('Management.employeetimetable',['location'=>$locationdata,'UserList'=>$userlist,'ListTimeSet'=>$timesetting,'LeavingSchedule'=>$leaveschedule]);
}
```

this is my controller

```
<li>
          <a href="{{action('ManagementController@EmployeeTimeTable')}}" class="dropdown-item">
            <p>Employee Timetable</p>
          </a>
        </li>
```

and this is code on blade to call controller@function

this step same as another controller, web, and blade.php. but, just for this rout get me a trouble. thank you

Comment: is your controller in a subfolder ?

Comment: What is the full namespace of your ManagementController controller ?

Comment: how you run the project in your localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with your route cache, simply do this:

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan route:cache
```

if you want to do same on the server you can define a route in `web.php` for that like this:

```
Route::get('/clear/route', 'ConfigController@clearRoute');
```

and make `ConfigController.php` like this

```
class ConfigController extends Controller
{
    public function clearRoute()
    {
        \Artisan::call('route:clear');
    }
}
```

and then go to that route on server example `http://your-domain/clear/route`

Answer (score 0):

If your controller is on a subfolder, and not in `app\Http\Controllers` you will need to provide the fully qualified class name of the controller to the action helper :

```
action('App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ManagementController@EmployeeTimeTable')
```

by default action helper will look for :  `App\Http\Controllers\ManagementController`

note that this syntax will not work as you might expect :

```
action('Admin\ManagementController@EmployeeTimeTable')
```

because laravel will not add `App\Http\Controllers` if there is a `\` in the action name parameter

Comment: I'm already used this method. but, still I'm got the same error.

Comment: check the FQCN of your controller, it has a wrong namespace or wrong file location

Comment: i'm already checking. but, I'm not getting anything different. but, I'm already fixing. with php artisan route:clear